# Adding index from *ngFor to [(ngModel)] in Angular (v4)

Tags: angular

I am using ngFor to iterate through an array and I need to bind the index to ngModel so that each input pair has an individual ID but I don't understand how I pass this in.

Here it is on plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q8NfhTL25Y8gOoGMXiP2?p=preview

Below is my current code:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index" class="row container-generic">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="container-input-checkbox">
          <label class="container-flex">
            <input class="pvq-create-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="" [(ngModel)]="needsUniqueID"> 
            <div class="pvq-create-label">
              <p>{{ question }}</p>
            </div>
          </label>
          <label [@hideShow]="needsUniqueID ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Answer
            <input type="textbox" name="">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need two-way binding? Could you not pass it with one-way? Like so `[uniqueID]="i"`

Comment: what do you want to accomplish, it is not clear from your code?

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder I want the answer input to only appear next to the question that is checked.

Comment: @tom would I replace "[(ngModel)]="needsUniqueID" with [uniqueID]="i" and [@hideShow]="needsUniqueID ? 'active' : 'inactive'" with [@hideShow]="uniqueID ? 'active' : 'inactive'"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the template reference variable (with index) for this instead of two-way-binding and change `inactive` and `active` to `false` and `true` for the animations. So your input would look like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="{{i}}" #name="ngModel" ngModel>
```

which now makes the unique `name.value` (based on index) to be `true` or `false` based on the state of the checkbox.

Therefore change `[@hideShow]` to:

```html
<label [@hideShow]="name.value ? 'true' : 'false'">Answer
  <input type="textbox" name="">
</label>
```

and in the component, replace `inactive` with `false` and `active` with `true` and you'll get your desired results :)

Here's your forked **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqUJqPmcyM80i7PH8NBQ?p=preview)**.

Comment: Great answer. Please, may you explain why the other instances created as a result of the `ngFor` loop aren't also bound to ngModel as they are in the original example? I've read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages 5 times and it's not clicking in my head.

Comment: @Tom You can think of this like if this were a form .. each `name` attribute we bind with `ngModel` is unique (being the index). That can be seen, if we transform this to a form: http://plnkr.co/edit/0F1o3TJGXAeeA8aM0Jhd?p=preview You can see that each `name` has the index value :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks for this! Is 'name="{{i}}" #name="ngModel" ngModel' equivalent to saying '[(ngModel)]={{i}}', which Angular doesn't allow?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **array of collections**.

Modify your json to have the below structure,

```
questions = [{ title :"What is your name?", needsUniqueID:'inactive'},
             {title:"What was your first pet's name?",needsUniqueID:'inactive' },
             {title :"Where were you born?" ,needsUniqueID:'active'}]
```

HTML will be as

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index" class="row container-generic">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="container-input-checkbox">
          <label class="container-flex">
            <input class="pvq-create-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="" [(ngModel)]="question.needsUniqueID"> 
            <div class="pvq-create-label">
              <p>{{question.title}}</p>
            </div>
          </label>
          <label [@hideShow]="question.needsUniqueID ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Answer
            <input type="textbox" name="">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/0XokdUQqy6iDklgmh8Uu?p=preview)**

Comment: Is this actually the best solution? it seems obtuse.

Comment: yes. this will be one of the best solution. you cannot handle using a single object as they will have same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a child component so that the state of whether it is checked or not is stored in the instance of the component as demonstrated by this [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uSDR77EcdD274QC18CGT?p=preview).

The child component could look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'question',
  styles: [
    '.pvq-create-label { display: inline-block }, container-flex{ clear: both; }'
  ],
  template: `
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="container-input-checkbox">
    <label class="container-flex">
      <input class="pvq-create-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="" [(ngModel)]="checked"> 
      <div class="pvq-create-label">
        <p>{{ question }}</p>
      </div>
    </label>
    <label [@hideShow]="checked ? 'active' : 'inactive'">Answer
      <input type="textbox" name="">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('hideShow', [
      state('inactive', style({
        opacity: 0,
        height: 0
      })),
      state('active', style({
        opacity: 1,
        height: '*'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('150ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('150ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class QuestionComponent {
  public checked: boolean
  @Input() question: string
}
```